# trying to malloc a series of arrays to contain names within an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Trying to make fill an array of pointers of a known size with blocks of memory I can later fill with names/pointers to said names. but when i go to compile it returns the following warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast 'opList[0] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(char)....'

any idea whats going on here and how to clear the warning?

```
#define QUE_SIZE 256
#define MAX_REWARDED 21
#define TWITCH_MAX 1 /*Temp*/

int main ()
{
 int* opList[5] = {NULL};
 setup(&opList);
}

void setup(int* opList)
{
  int *x;
  int *y;

  opList[0] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(char) * QUE_SIZE * TWITCH_MAX);     /*currentNames*/
  opList[1] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_REWARDED); /*correctAnswers*/
  opList[2] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * QUE_SIZE);     /*chronoQue*/
  opList[3] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * QUE_SIZE);     /*rewardQue*/
  opList[4] = NULL; /*End in NULL to make garbage collection easy*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `void setup(int* opList)` is not correct. Chnage it to `void setup(int* opList[5])`
2. call the `setup()` as `setup(opList);`
3. add a forward declaration of `setup()`.

Note : Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Corrected code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define QUE_SIZE 256
#define MAX_REWARDED 21
#define TWITCH_MAX 1 /*Temp*/

void setup(int* opList[5]);

int main ()
{
 int* opList[5] = {NULL};
 setup(opList);
}

void setup(int* opList[5])
{
//  int *x;
//  int *y;

  opList[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * QUE_SIZE * TWITCH_MAX);     /*currentNames*/
  opList[1] = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_REWARDED); /*correctAnswers*/
  opList[2] = malloc(sizeof(int) * QUE_SIZE);     /*chronoQue*/
  opList[3] = malloc(sizeof(int) * QUE_SIZE);     /*rewardQue*/
  opList[4] = NULL; /*End in NULL to make garbage collection easy*/

}
```

Comment: don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Right !! should've been noticed that part while copying the code.

Comment: It would be nice if the forward declaration and the definition used the same prototype (which should be `int **opList`).

Answer (score 0):

Compile with warnings:

```
note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int * (*)[5]’
```

Change

```
void setup(int* opList)
```

to

```
void setup(int* opList[5])
```

call it using `setup(opList);`

And `opList[0] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(char) * QUE_SIZE * TWITCH_MAX);` may be wrong if `QUE_SIZE * TWITCH_MAX` is not a multiple of `sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 0):

In the `setup` function definition, you declare `opList` as a simple pointer to `int`, so the expression `opList[i]` will have type `int`, hence the warning.

The expression `&opList` has type `int *(*)[5]`, or "pointer to 5-element array of pointer to `int`", which is not necessarily what you need in this case.

You can simply pass `opList` in the function call (no `&` necessary), but you will need to change the prototype to `int **opList`:

```
setup( opList ); // function call

void setup( int **opList )
{
  opList[i] = malloc(...); // cast not necessary in C
  ...
}
```

Except when it's the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an expression of type "array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.  In this case, `T` is `int *`.  That's why the prototype is `int **opList`.  Note that the expression `opList[i]` will have type `int *`.

I'm worried about you storing text data in `opList[0]`; that's going to require some casting gymnastics later on, but we'll deal with that when it becomes a problem.